# How is incorrect UDP length field usually handled by network stack?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

I am designing yet another UDP network stack. I wonder how incorrect values of UDP field in the UDP header are usually handled. Specifically, when the UDP length field indicates larger UDP payload than it actually is. For example, this could happen when all the fragments are received (the last packet had the MF flag cleared) and as the datagram is being reassembled it is found out that not all the UDP data were received.

After some exploring it seems that no RFC defines how these datagrams should be handled. Clearly, one approach is to discard the whole datagram and the other to ignore the UDP length field inconsistency. I would welcome if somebody would share experience how this is implemented on various platforms.

Comment: A reassembled UDP datagram which is missing any piece is dropped because it is not a valid UDP datagram.